# Combination Operators on Sensors Arrays Data

Tags: matlab, join, matrix

Is there any standardized operators over data from arrays of sensors?

I am normally dealing with sensors data in the form of `time + channels`. The time is a timestamp, and the channels are the available data for these timestamps. All these fields are numeric, no strings involved.

Normally I have to mix those data objects in different ways. Let's suppose `M1` is size `m1xn1` and `M2` is size `m2xn2`:

- Combine rows of data from the same channels and different timestamps (i.e. `n1 == n2`). This leads to a vertical concatenation `[M1; M2]`.
- Combine columns of data from the same timestamps and different channels, (i.e. `m1 == m2`). This leads to a horizontal concatenation `[M1 M2]`.

These operators are trivial and well defined.

When I have slight differences, for example, a few additional samples in `M1` or `M2`, everything turns complicated and I have to think in weird schemes to perform such operations, such as these:

- Cleaning the exceeding samples on `M1` or `M2`, for matching the dimensions.
- Calculate an aggregated timestamp, obtaining a `unique(sort())` on the timestamps, and then apply a union like in a SQL `JOIN` sentence.
- Aggregate the data on `M1` or `M2`, this is, reducing `m1` or `m2` to a smaller figure, resampling the timescale, and then apply an aggregation like in a SQL `GROUP` sentence.

I cannot think of a unique and definite function to combine this sort of data. How can I do this?

Comment: Are values unique between `M1` and `M2`? In other words, could the same combination of time stamp and channel appear in both?

Comment: Normally no, the data is different most of the time :/

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an `m1`-element vector of time values `t1` and and `n1`-element vector of channel values `c1` for your `m1`-by-`n1` matrix `M1` (and likewise for `M2`). First and foremost, you will likely need to convert your time and channel values into equivalent index values. You can do this by expanding your time and channel values into grids using [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html), then converting them to index values using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[t1, c1] = ndgrid(t1, c1);
[t2, c2] = ndgrid(t2, c2);
[tUnion, ~, tIndex] = unique([t1(:); t2(:)]);
[cUnion, ~, cIndex] = unique([c1(:); c2(:)]);
```

Now there are two approaches you can take for aggregating the data using the above indices. If you know for certain that the matrices `M1` and `M2` will never contain repeated measurements (i.e. the same combination of time and channel will not appear in both), then you can build the final joined matrix by creating a linear index from `tIndex` and `cIndex` and combining the values from `M1` and `M2` like so:

```
MUnion = zeros(numel(tUnion), numel(cUnion));
MUnion(tIndex+numel(tUnion).*(cIndex-1)) = [M1(:); M2(:)];
```

If the matrices `M1` and `M2` could contain repeated measurements at the same combination of time and channel values, then [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) will be the way to go. You will have to decide how you want to combine the repeated measurements, such as taking the mean as shown here:

```
MUnion = accumarray([tIndex cIndex], [M1(:); M2(:)], [], @mean);
```